# What are the minimums of $x^y+y^x$ and $x^y+y^z+z^x$?

Tags: calculus, optimization, exponential-function, exponentiation, maxima-minima

What are the minima of $x^y+y^x$ and $x^y+y^z+z^x$ on $\{x,y,z\}\subset\mathbb R^+ $?

I was able to show that $x^y+y^x > 1$, but is this the best possible bound? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Try $x\rightarrow0+$ and $y=0.5$.

Comment: OKay so for the case of 2 variables 1 is the best we can do.

Comment: The values of your functions are not always real: $x^y+y^x$ for $x=-1$ and $y=1/2$ is $(-1)^{1/2} + (1/2)^{-1}=\sqrt{-1}+2=2+i\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$? This means there is no minimum since $\mathbb C$ is not ordered.

Comment: It is unbounded from below so there is no minimum. E.g., set $x = -10^{1000}$ and $y=1$...

Comment: Surely you want $x,y,z\ge0$ otherwise the question is more than a bit ill-formed.

Comment: Obviously, $x,y,z>0$.

Answer (score 2):

We'll prove that $$\inf_{\{x,y,z\}\subset(0,+\infty)}(x^y+y^z+z^x)=1.$$
Indeed, we can assume that $\{x,y,z\}\subset(0,1)$.

Now, by Bernoulli $$\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^y=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^y<1+y\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)=\frac{x+y-xy}{x}.$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{cyc}x^y>\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+y-xy}>\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+y}>  \sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+y+z}=1$$
and since for $y=0$ and $x\rightarrow+\infty$ we get $\sum\limits_{cyc}x^y\rightarrow1$, we are done!

Comment: Nice! That covers the generalized case of $n$ variables.

Comment: @mtheorylord Fix please your post. All variables should be positives.

Comment: OK. Done, fixed.

Comment: @mtheorylord Thank you! I think in the general the answer is $1$ again.